# OpenSSH + Kerberos SSO: No key table entry found for host/localhost.localdomain

Tags: ssh, kerberos, single-sign-on, gssapi, scientific-linux

SSO not working with OpenSSH - I have not been able to get GSSAPIAuthentication to work with Kerberos. Everytime I attempted to login, I kept getting prompted for the password.

During the troubleshooting, I initiated a debug here:

```
[foster@kvm0007 ~]$ kinit
Password for foster@MONZELL.COM: 
[foster@kvm0007 ~]$ ssh -p222 -K foster@kerberos.monzell.com -vvv
OpenSSH_5.3p1, OpenSSL 1.0.0-fips 29 Mar 2010
debug1: Reading configuration data /home/users/foster/.ssh/config
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: Applying options for *
debug2: ssh_connect: needpriv 0
debug1: Connecting to kerberos.monzell.com [192.168.15.100] port 222.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: identity file /home/users/foster/.ssh/identity type -1
debug1: identity file /home/users/foster/.ssh/id_rsa type -1
debug3: Not a RSA1 key file /home/users/foster/.ssh/id_dsa.
debug2: key_type_from_name: unknown key type '-----BEGIN'
debug3: key_read: missing keytype
debug3: key_read: missing whitespace
debug3: key_read: missing whitespace
debug3: key_read: missing whitespace
debug3: key_read: missing whitespace
debug3: key_read: missing whitespace
debug3: key_read: missing whitespace
debug3: key_read: missing whitespace
debug3: key_read: missing whitespace
debug3: key_read: missing whitespace
debug3: key_read: missing whitespace
debug2: key_type_from_name: unknown key type '-----END'
debug3: key_read: missing keytype
debug1: identity file /home/users/foster/.ssh/id_dsa type 2
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version OpenSSH_5.3
debug1: match: OpenSSH_5.3 pat OpenSSH*
debug1: Enabling compatibility mode for protocol 2.0
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_5.3
debug2: fd 3 setting O_NONBLOCK
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
debug3: Wrote 792 bytes for a total of 813
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha1,diffie-hellman-group14-sha1,diffie-hellman-group1-sha1
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: ssh-rsa,ssh-dss
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,arcfour256,arcfour128,aes128-cbc,3des-cbc,blowfish-cbc,cast128-cbc,aes192-cbc,aes256-cbc,arcfour,rijndael-cbc@lysator.liu.se
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,arcfour256,arcfour128,aes128-cbc,3des-cbc,blowfish-cbc,cast128-cbc,aes192-cbc,aes256-cbc,arcfour,rijndael-cbc@lysator.liu.se
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: hmac-md5,hmac-sha1,umac-64@openssh.com,hmac-ripemd160,hmac-ripemd160@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-96,hmac-md5-96
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: hmac-md5,hmac-sha1,umac-64@openssh.com,hmac-ripemd160,hmac-ripemd160@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-96,hmac-md5-96
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: none,zlib@openssh.com,zlib
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: none,zlib@openssh.com,zlib
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: 
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: 
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: first_kex_follows 0 
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: reserved 0 
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha1,diffie-hellman-group14-sha1,diffie-hellman-group1-sha1
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: ssh-rsa,ssh-dss
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,arcfour256,arcfour128,aes128-cbc,3des-cbc,blowfish-cbc,cast128-cbc,aes192-cbc,aes256-cbc,arcfour,rijndael-cbc@lysator.liu.se
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,arcfour256,arcfour128,aes128-cbc,3des-cbc,blowfish-cbc,cast128-cbc,aes192-cbc,aes256-cbc,arcfour,rijndael-cbc@lysator.liu.se
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: hmac-md5,hmac-sha1,umac-64@openssh.com,hmac-ripemd160,hmac-ripemd160@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-96,hmac-md5-96
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: hmac-md5,hmac-sha1,umac-64@openssh.com,hmac-ripemd160,hmac-ripemd160@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-96,hmac-md5-96
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: none,zlib@openssh.com
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: none,zlib@openssh.com
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: 
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: 
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: first_kex_follows 0 
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: reserved 0 
debug2: mac_setup: found hmac-md5
debug1: kex: server->client aes128-ctr hmac-md5 none
debug2: mac_setup: found hmac-md5
debug1: kex: client->server aes128-ctr hmac-md5 none
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_REQUEST(1024<1024<8192) sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_GROUP
debug3: Wrote 24 bytes for a total of 837
debug2: dh_gen_key: priv key bits set: 132/256
debug2: bits set: 499/1024
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_INIT sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_REPLY
debug3: Wrote 144 bytes for a total of 981
debug3: put_host_port: [192.168.15.100]:222
debug3: put_host_port: [kerberos.monzell.com]:222
debug3: check_host_in_hostfile: filename /home/users/foster/.ssh/known_hosts
debug3: check_host_in_hostfile: filename /etc/ssh/ssh_known_hosts
debug3: check_host_in_hostfile: filename /home/users/foster/.ssh/known_hosts
debug3: check_host_in_hostfile: filename /etc/ssh/ssh_known_hosts
debug1: checking without port identifier
debug3: check_host_in_hostfile: filename /home/users/foster/.ssh/known_hosts
debug3: check_host_in_hostfile: match line 1
debug3: check_host_in_hostfile: filename /home/users/foster/.ssh/known_hosts
debug3: check_host_in_hostfile: match line 1
debug1: Host 'kerberos.monzell.com' is known and matches the RSA host key.
debug1: Found key in /home/users/foster/.ssh/known_hosts:1
debug1: found matching key w/out port
debug2: bits set: 505/1024
debug1: ssh_rsa_verify: signature correct
debug2: kex_derive_keys
debug2: set_newkeys: mode 1
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
debug3: Wrote 16 bytes for a total of 997
debug2: set_newkeys: mode 0
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_REQUEST sent
debug3: Wrote 48 bytes for a total of 1045
debug2: service_accept: ssh-userauth
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
debug2: key: /home/users/foster/.ssh/identity ((nil))
debug2: key: /home/users/foster/.ssh/id_rsa ((nil))
debug2: key: /home/users/foster/.ssh/id_dsa (0x7fed559e5d30)
debug3: Wrote 64 bytes for a total of 1109
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic,password
debug3: start over, passed a different list publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic,password
debug3: preferred gssapi-with-mic,publickey,keyboard-interactive,password
debug3: authmethod_lookup gssapi-with-mic
debug3: remaining preferred: publickey,keyboard-interactive,password
debug3: authmethod_is_enabled gssapi-with-mic
debug1: Next authentication method: gssapi-with-mic
debug3: Trying to reverse map address 192.168.15.100.
debug2: we sent a gssapi-with-mic packet, wait for reply
debug3: Wrote 96 bytes for a total of 1205
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic,password
debug2: we sent a gssapi-with-mic packet, wait for reply
debug3: Wrote 96 bytes for a total of 1301
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic,password
debug2: we sent a gssapi-with-mic packet, wait for reply
debug3: Wrote 96 bytes for a total of 1397
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic,password
debug2: we sent a gssapi-with-mic packet, wait for reply
debug3: Wrote 96 bytes for a total of 1493
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic,password
debug2: we did not send a packet, disable method
debug3: authmethod_lookup publickey
debug3: remaining preferred: keyboard-interactive,password
debug3: authmethod_is_enabled publickey
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Trying private key: /home/users/foster/.ssh/identity
debug3: no such identity: /home/users/foster/.ssh/identity
debug1: Trying private key: /home/users/foster/.ssh/id_rsa
debug3: no such identity: /home/users/foster/.ssh/id_rsa
debug1: Offering public key: /home/users/foster/.ssh/id_dsa
debug3: send_pubkey_test
debug2: we sent a publickey packet, wait for reply
debug3: Wrote 528 bytes for a total of 2021
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic,password
debug2: we did not send a packet, disable method
debug3: authmethod_lookup password
debug3: remaining preferred: ,password
debug3: authmethod_is_enabled password
debug1: Next authentication method: password
foster@kerberos.monzell.com's password:
```

As you can see, gssapi-with-mic is being sent, but no decreeable response.

As it turns out, it appears that this is was being sent to the KDC:

```
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
debug1: kex: client->server aes128-ctr hmac-md5 none
debug1: kex: server->client aes128-ctr hmac-md5 none
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_REQUEST received
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_GROUP sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_INIT
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_REPLY sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
debug1: KEX done
debug1: userauth-request for user foster service ssh-connection method none
debug1: attempt 0 failures 0
debug1: PAM: initializing for "foster"
debug1: PAM: setting PAM_RHOST to "192.168.15.37"
debug1: PAM: setting PAM_TTY to "ssh"
debug1: userauth-request for user foster service ssh-connection method gssapi-with-mic
debug1: attempt 1 failures 0
debug1: Unspecified GSS failure.  Minor code may provide more information
**No key table entry found for host/localhost.localdomain@MONZELL.COM**

debug1: userauth-request for user foster service ssh-connection method gssapi-with-mic
debug1: attempt 2 failures 0
debug1: userauth-request for user foster service ssh-connection method gssapi-with-mic
debug1: attempt 3 failures 0
debug1: userauth-request for user foster service ssh-connection method gssapi-with-mic
debug1: attempt 4 failures 0
debug1: userauth-request for user foster service ssh-connection method publickey
debug1: attempt 5 failures 0
debug1: test whether pkalg/pkblob are acceptable
debug1: temporarily_use_uid: 502/502 (e=0/0)
debug1: trying public key file /home/users/foster/.ssh/authorized_keys
debug1: restore_uid: 0/0
debug1: temporarily_use_uid: 502/502 (e=0/0)
debug1: trying public key file /home/users/foster/.ssh/authorized_keys2
debug1: restore_uid: 0/0
```

Some research indicated it may be an issue with the host file, which I have as follows:

```
[foster@sl6 ~]$ cat /etc/hosts
127.0.0.1       localhost.localdomain   localhost
::1     sl6     localhost6.localdomain6 localhost6
192.168.15.100  kerberos.monzell.com kerberos
192.168.15.100 monzell.com
192.168.15.31   kvm0001.monzell.com     kvm0001
```

I attempted to try to set the hostname manual on the host, with no effect.

Here are the list of principals at the KDC:

```
[root@sl6 ~]# kadmin.local
Authenticating as principal rilindo/admin@MONZELL.COM with password.
kadmin.local:  listprincs
K/M@MONZELL.COM
foster@MONZELL.COM
host/kerberos.monzell.com@MONZELL.COM
host/kvm0007.monzell.com@MONZELL.COM
joe@MONZELL.COM
kadmin/admin@MONZELL.COM
kadmin/changepw@MONZELL.COM
kadmin/sl6@MONZELL.COM
krbtgt/MONZELL.COM@MONZELL.COM
monzell@MONZELL.COM
rilindo/admin@MONZELL.COM
rilindo@MONZELL.COM
```

Kerberos does most of the authentication. The user directory resides in OpenLDAP. Both the client and server are running Scientific Linux 6.1, with the client running as a VM on top of the server.

I can confirm that Kerberos works outside of OpenSSH, as indicated here:

```
[foster@kvm0007 ~]$ /usr/kerberos/bin/krsh -x -PN kerberos.monzell.com
This rlogin session is encrypting all data transmissions.
Last login: Sun Sep 25 21:18:20 from 192.168.15.37
```

The user(s) in question have the following ssh config file:

```
[foster@sl6 ~]$ cat .ssh/config 
GSSAPIAuthentication yes
GSSAPIDelegateCredentials yes
GSSAPITrustDns yes
```

What direction should I go from this point?

EDIT: I knew I forgot to add something to this post. Here is the krb5.conf on the server:

```
[root@sl6 ~]# cat /etc/krb5.conf
[logging]
 default = FILE:/var/log/krb5libs.log
 kdc = FILE:/var/log/krb5kdc.log
 admin_server = FILE:/var/log/kadmind.log

[libdefaults]
 default_realm = MONZELL.COM
 dns_lookup_realm = false
 dns_lookup_kdc = false
 ticket_lifetime = 24h
 renew_lifetime = 7d
 forwardable = true

[realms]
 MONZELL.COM = {
  kdc = kerberos.monzell.com
  admin_server = kerberos.monzell.com
 }

[domain_realm]
 .monzell.com = MONZELL.COM
 monzell.com = MONZELL.COM
```

And on the client:

```
[rilindo@kvm0007 ~]$ cat /etc/krb5.conf
[logging]
 default = FILE:/var/log/krb5libs.log
 kdc = FILE:/var/log/krb5kdc.log
 admin_server = FILE:/var/log/kadmind.log

[libdefaults]
 default_realm = MONZELL.COM
 dns_lookup_realm = false
 dns_lookup_kdc = false
 ticket_lifetime = 24h
 renew_lifetime = 7d
 forwardable = true

[realms]
 EXAMPLE.COM = {
  kdc = kerberos.example.com
  admin_server = kerberos.example.com
 }

 MONZELL.COM = {
  kdc = kerberos.monzell.com
  admin_server = kerberos.monzell.com
 }

[domain_realm]
 .example.com = EXAMPLE.COM
 example.com = EXAMPLE.COM
 monzell.com = MONZELL.COM
 .monzell.com = MONZELL.COM
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Could be a simple host name issue or a domain realm mapping issue.
(It's probably the first one, but for completeness here are both.)

**hostname issue**
`hostname -f` on kerberos.monzell.com
should return: `kerberos.monzell.com`
should *not* return: `localhost.localdomain`

**domain realm mapping issue**
`dig -t txt _kerberos.kerberos.monzell.com`
`dig -t txt _kerberos.monzell.com`

If you don't want to use `/etc/krb5.conf` should return
`<record> <ttl num> IN  TXT "MONZELL.COM".`

However, given hosts file this is probably not the case.
`/etc/krb5.conf` should contain either:

> [domain_realm]
>   .monzell.com MONZELL.COM

or

> > [domain_realm]
> >     kerberos.monzell.com MONZELL.COM

Comment: Are you referring to the client or  server?

Comment: hostname -> server. domain realm mapping -> client(s). Note a server machine can have client processes, though that doesn't seem applicable here.

Comment: You're right. Kerberos is looking at the hostname of the server, not the DNS name. Changed the hostname made the error go away. I have a different error now, but I'll post that later. :}